# Translate SQL to linq or lambda in C#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

How to translate this line of T-SQL to linq or lambda?

Given below list.

**SQL**

```
select sum (amount)
from
    (select Qty * price as amount 
     from purchaseItems) as table2
```

**C#**

```
List<purchaseItems> items = new List<purchaseItems>();
double gst = 0;
double total = 0;
```

Comment: A simple LINQ version would be: `var sum = items.Sum(i => i.Qty * i.price);` assuming `items` is a filled list of `purchaseItems`.

Comment: thanks. i will try this.

Comment: short and sweet compared to sql. Thanks man.

Comment: your original sql sounds quite weird anyway: what about `select sum (Qty * price) from purchaseItems`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've loaded everything on your `List<purchaseItems> items` and there is the property `Amount` you can do summation using LINQ lambda like this.

```
double total = items.Sum(r => r.Amount);
```

or

```
double total = items.Sum(r => r.Qty * r.Price);
```

Comment: I think `Amount` is Qty * price, check my comment.

Comment: there is no property called amount. i am getting it from sub query.